# Method of undetermined coefficients for non-homogeneous linear system with two constant vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have a system of non-homogeneous linear first order differential equations:

$$ x'=A x+b_0+b_1t $$

Where $A$ is a $2\times2$ invertible matrix, $b_0$ and $b_1$ are:

$$ b_0 =
\begin{pmatrix}
        r\\
        u\\
        \end{pmatrix}, \qquad 
 b_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
        m\\
        n\\
        \end{pmatrix}
 $$

A particular solution for this system is given:

$$ x_p=g_1+g_2t $$

where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are constant vectors. Would I be able to find these constant vectors by determining them independently? Meaning I split them up like this:

$$ g_1=-A^{-1}b_0  \\
g_2=-A^{-1}b_1 $$

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out.

$$ A(g_1+g_2t)+b_0+b_1t $$

$$ =Ag_1+Ag_2t+b_0+b_1t $$

$$ =Ag_1+b_0+(Ag_2+b_1)t $$

$g_1$ and $g_2$ can now be determined by solving the above system of equations.